# Prioritize wildcard mappings in Spring

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, controller

I'm wondering if it's possible to set priorities for controllers for wildcard mappings. For example, I want to be able to map the following:

```
/**
/static/**
/resources/**
```

And have the static and resources take precedence before the catchall. I've tried having my global controller implementing Ordered and using `ResourceHandlerRegistry.setOrder()` for the latter two (and also setting the order on the viewResolver to a lower priorty), but that doesn't seem to work. I haven't found any real good resources detailing how to do this. Anyone know how, or if it's even possible?

Thanks for any help provided.

Edit:
Config is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mysite" )
public class BaseConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    /**
     * Allow us to map a custom directory for resources.
     */
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/inc/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/views/ajaxincludes/");
        registry.setOrder(1);
    }

    /**
     * view resolver
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver configureInternalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setOrder(2);
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post your spring conf.

Comment: @jintian-deng Added config file. Took me long enough.

Comment: I'd be curious to know if this ever got fixed. I've got the same issue & have been trying the same kind of code.